# Why is VS Code trying to run my C++ code as Python when pressing F5?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am very new to C++ and I've wanted to learn it.
I have installed gdb v. 12.1, g++ v. 12.1.0 and gcc 12.1.0 using Msys2 as the tutorials I have followed have told me to. Additionally I have copied this line of code to print out "Hello world!" from the tutorial.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is that if I run the code I get an error saying "Syntax error" with an arrow pointing towards the "using namespace std;" line.

[image]

Apparently Visual Studio Code has tried to execute the code as Python. The code runs when I press the debug button top right of the screen. But when I press the F5 key, then it tries to run Python instead. How can I make it so when I press F5 then it compiles and runs my file as C++?

I have installed the C/C++ extension and I have a launch.json file as well.

**Tasks.json file:**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**Launch.json file:**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
    ]
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to run my code, thanks everyone for the help. But one more thing, the code only runs when i press the debug button top right of the screen (Im using VS code). But when i press the f5 key, then it runs my python file instead, which is not what i want, i am very used to pressing the f5 key to run my code so i would be happy if there was a way to use the f5 key to run my c++ file and not my python file

Comment: Maybe you have code-runner installed and it's improperly configured??